# Django db block for migration with no schema change

Tags: django, django-migrations

When updating the `helptext` of field of a Django model, it produces a migration to track this change. This operation doesn't perform any sql query (checked with `manage.py sqlmigrate myapp`).

However, does it still lock the table like normal schema change migration?

Comment: No, if no SQL is being run then tables will not be locked